# Deal with a variable number of samples associated with identificative values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm a new member and not an Excel ace!

My problem is that I've (for example, the dataset is much larger) five identification values (id1,id2,id3,id4,id5) in the column A which identify a cast. In column B I've 19 samples for the 5 casts in column A. However, in each cast the sample size vary from 2 to 6. So, I want to obtain 19 values in the way that each cast identification value correspond to its number of samples. In the end I want to have this kind of column A with the identification values (id1,id1,id2,id2,id2,id2,id3,id3,id3,id3,id3,id4,id4,id4,id4,id4,id4,id5,id5) which correspond with the column B with the number of samples (1,2,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2). So, I want each identification value to correspond to the number of its samples.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Hi Nelly, I edited my question, I hope now is clearer. Thank you

Comment: It would be great if you provide some **`sample test data`** and **`result data`**. I am still having hard time understanding your requirement.

Comment: Hi Nelly, thanks again for your effort in the understanding. Please find here the example of the dataset: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ar59--FnHMRsGGMYmd3DOWY5l7MtmlgMmpi5EYpz1oA/edit#gid=0

Comment: My interpretation of your requirement is as follows. The number of values in column A matches the number of 1s in column B. The values in column A are to be saved and then cleared.  Each saved value is placed against a 1 and then duplicated down to the next 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be best served by instead creating a "CAST+Sample" column that would uniquely identify each row.  However the below, entered into A3 should produce the desired effect from your example.

=IF(B3=1,"ID"&VALUE(RIGHT(A1,1))+1,A2)

This will only work when there are less than 10 Casts.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! However I need to use the formula for some thousand casts.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it was worth giving example data. Assuming your `Sample` is in column `B` and you want your `ID's` in column `A`. Put this formula in cell `A2` and drag till you have your `Sample`.

```
=IF(VALUE(B2)=1,IF(LEFT(A1,2)="ID","ID"&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)+1,"ID1"),IF(LEFT(A1,2)="ID",A1,"ID1"))
```

Here is the screenshot of how it will look after you place this formula.

[image]

Comment: Glad to help you out.

Comment: @Nely27281 Great work at understanding the requirements from the description just not possible. This formula will also work: `=IF(N2<>1,L1, "ID"&IF(L1=L$1,1, SUM(SUBSTITUTE(L1,"ID","")+1)))`